# Synchronization of NSUserDefault's on allocation increases memory.

Tags: iphone, uiimage, memory-management, nsuserdefaults

Hello. I am using `NSUserdefault`'s for storing the image name from one of the controllers (on the click of a button) which sets the background image of the rest of the controllers. I am also synchronizing the default so that everything works fine. ***BUT***, the problem arises when I open the allocation tool, whenever I am changing the image name and synchronising the `NSUserDefault`'s on the click of the button, the allocation shows an increase in memory allocation of about **1 MB**.

So if anyone knows why this is happening, or has the solution then, could you please let me know?

Comment: Something must not be getting released. We'd have to see some code to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer ,instead of setting background with the code
[self.view setBackgroundColor[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]]];

I have taken an imageView and used it's property to set the background of viewcontroller's view.It's working fine but still I need to know why not my first apporach?